# On the construction of hyperelliptic Riemann surfaces.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I have seen two ways to construct hyperelliptic curves, and it seems to me that the intuition behind the change of coordinate is not the same. I like better the second construction (which is pretty topological), but understand better the intuition of the first one (which is more analytical).

**First construction.**
In my lecture notes, one constructs an hyperelliptic curve as follow : consider the Riemann surface $X \subset \mathbb C^2$ defined by $y^2 = p(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x) = (x-a_1) \dots (x-a_k)$ such that $a_i \neq a_j$ whenever $i \neq j$. Then, the holomorphic function $\pi \colon (x,y) \mapsto x$ is a ramified covering of degree 2 (the branching points being $a_1, \ldots, a_k$).

The idea is now to extend this ramified covering to a application $\tilde X \to \mathbb P^1$ of degree 2. In order to do that, observe that when $x \to \infty$, also $y \to \infty$, and let be two new local coordinates $z = 1/x$, $w = 1/y$. Then pulling back a small punctured disk centered in $0$ by $z$ and rewritting $y^2 = p(x)$ as $w^2 = 1/p(1/z)$, it appears that we can extend $\pi$ above $z = 0$ by one or two points depending of the parity of $k$. We then have the wanted $\tilde X$, compact Riemann surface.

**Second construction.** (Ref. Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*) As before we have $X \subset \mathbb C^2$ and we also construct $Y \subset \mathbb C^2$ defined by $w^2 = z^{2m} p(1/z)$ where $k=2m$ or $2m-1$. Then let the biholomorphism
$$\varphi \colon \{(x,y) \in X \mid x \neq 0\} \to \{(z,w) \in Y \mid z \neq 0\}, (x,y) \mapsto (z,w) = (1/x, y/x^m),$$
and we obtain $\tilde X$ by glueing $X$ and $Y$ over $\varphi$.

**Question.** What is the intuition behind the change of coordinates $z=1/x$, $w=y/x^m$ in the second construction ? It does not seems natural to me, whereas the change $z=1/x$, $w=1/y$ does. In other words, where does it come that we set $Y$ as the locus of $w^2 = z^{2m}p(1/z)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this answer can give an "intuition", but at least some sort of explanation of why it makes sense to consider the change $w=y/x^m$. The idea is that you start with the curve $y^2=p(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and want to define some smooth compactification of it. The easiest idea would be to take the projective closure in $\mathbb{P}^2$, but a direct computation shows that this procedure always adds exactly one point, which is singular as soon as $k\geq 4$, so this does not work.

Another approach is to consider a line bundle $L$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$. Over an affine chart $\mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{P}^1$ the bundle trivializes, giving a copy of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then you take your curve $y^2=p(x)$ in "this" $\mathbb{C}^2$ and consider the closure of it as a subspace of the (total space of the) line bundle $L$. To do this you need to check what happens in the fiber when you go to the other affine chart $\mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{P}^1$ via $z=1/x$. Fact: line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are classified by their degree, thus $L$ will be of the form $\mathcal{O}(k)$ for some $k$; the change of coordinates in the fibers of $L=\mathcal{O}(k)$ is exactly given by $w=y/x^k$. Direct computations show that the right choice of $k$ (i.e. of $L$) allows you to extend the curve adding one or two smooth points over the point at infinity in the base (i.e. $z=0$). The curve you have called $Y$ is exactly the affine part of this compactification in the trivialization of $L$ over the $z$-chart, and the values you have written for $k$ are the right ones, of course depending on the parity of $deg(p)$.

Comment: Hyper elliptic Riemann surface is kind of compactification of affine algebraic curves?